# App published in Google Play doesn't appear in search

Tags: android, google-play

My app is alive for a week, but when I search for the app name in Google play, I don't get any result listing my app. How long time takes a new app to appear in search?

Thanks so much!

Comment: 24 hours to reflect in world-wide Google servers.

Comment: *"24 hours to reflect in world-wide Google servers"* @JonGoodwin the topicstarter claims that app already is live for a week..

Comment: but on the other side how many new people are going to search on app name anyway in Google Play/Google web search .....

Comment: Is your app release alpha or beta? Alpha release does not appear in Play Store and Beta only for test users.

Comment: it is released publicly. It appears in the store if I write the link in the browser or open directly the link in the phone. It doesn't appear if I search by name.

Comment: I have contacted Google 28 hours ago but no answer

Comment: Raymond, In the places where it is difficult to post links e.g. Instagram I will tell future users to search by the app name in the App Stores. It works perfectly with iOS, why it does not work in Google Play?

Comment: If you don't have enough *unique* keywords in the name (*uniqueness*), it won't show up. Google, say, **"We do the best we can with search. Sometimes apps don't show up for a certain term"** See [App visibility & discovery issues](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9042516?visit_id=637053077976199619-1462980723&hl=en&rd=1#ts=3056735). Best is to have your Google app name White-listed (good-luck with that !).

Answer (score 0):

if your app is already live then search by package name otherwise contact google, usually it takes maximum 24 hours.

Comment: I need to search by app name and have it listed. Why other apps with similar names appear but not mine when I search by name?

Comment: And not, it doesn't appear either if I search by package name :(  But if I use a direct link I can see the app in Google Play (published, other users can also see it and download

Comment: @iColorama Did you know the reason ?